# PHP script taking too long to echo the data

Tags: php

My PHP script is taking too long to echo the data in a file. It seems that I have gone wrong with some loops and its taking too long to process.Could anyone please look at my code and let me know where i went wrong?
My task is to loop through the JSON data array and echo the data in XML tags.
My json array looks like following
[["GENERIC SALES PRICE", ""],["REGION", "SALE PRICE"],["AMERICA", "260,000"],["ASIA","340,000"],..etc]

```
$fp = fopen("data_save2.json", "r");
$inp=file_get_contents("data_save2.json");
fclose($fp);
$inp=json_decode($inp);
$inp_info=$inp;
$start_row=0;
$start_col=0;
for($i=0; $i <= $inp_info; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j <= $inp_info; $j++) {
        if ($inp_info[$i][$j]=='GENERIC SALES PRICE') {
          $start_row=$i+1;
          $start_col=$j;
            }     
$row_index=$start_row;
      $rows_of_data=0;

   while($inp_info[$row_index][$start_col]!=''){
    $rows_of_data = $rows_of_data+1;
    $row_index = $row_index+1;}
    }
} 
$dir = "C:/../data/GenericSalePrice.xml";
  $fp = fopen($dir, 'w');     
  fwrite($fp,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>');
  fwrite($fp,"\n");
  fwrite($fp,'<generic-sales-price xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">');
  fwrite($fp,"\n");
  for($j=0; $j<=$rows_of_data; $j++){
    fwrite($fp,"\t<sale-price>\n");
    $region = $inp_info[$start_row+$j][$start_col];
    fwrite($fp, "\t\t<region>");        
    fwrite($fp,"$region");
    fwrite($fp, "</region>\n");
    $price =$inp_info[$start_row+$j][$start_col+1];
    fwrite($fp, "\t\t<price>");
    fwrite($fp, "$price");
    fwrite($fp, "</price>\n");
    fwrite($fp, "\t</sale-price>\n");

        }  

fwrite($fp, "</generic-sales-price>");

    fclose($fp);
```

Please help me with this,
Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is the file? That is, file size (mb/gb) and number of lines

Comment: The input file is just 10*2 array..The output xml file contains ~20 lines

Comment: Since you're on a local machine (Windows) try using backslashes instead `$dir = "C:\..\data\GenericSalePrice.xml";` you might even have to use double backslashes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ?? Creating the output file isn't the problem - it's the creation taking too long

Comment: Why you using fopen and file_get_contents on the same file? And why aren't you using foreach loop?

Comment: why are you writing so many times to the file? why not build your string first and then write once? writing to disk is expensive.

Comment: @austin +1, Completely agreed

Comment: i would also comment on 2 things. 1). for readability purposes, i would have different file handler variable names so that it does not get confusing as to which file handlers are handling the opening and closing of specific files. 2). what is the purose of `$inp_info=$inp;` ?

Comment: @user2791530 Deffo read `austin`'s comment and change the code accordingly - didn't even notice. Build the string in a variable first (shove in `"\n"` if you want newlines), then write the whole lot to the file at once at the end.

Comment: @austin : I dont know how to write to a string and then write it to the file. Could you please let me know how to do it?Thanks for looking

Comment: just assign everything to a variable like $content = 'stuff';$content .= 'second stuff'; and so on

Comment: I am getting Undefined offset notice at the  while($inp_info[$row_index][$start_col]!='') and also at the if(inp_info[i][j]=="GENERIC SALES PRICE').. What do you guys think is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug..
I was using

```
for($i=0; $i <= $inp_info; $i++) {
for($j=0; $j <= $inp_info; $j++) {
```

Now, I have changed it to

```
for($i=0; $i <= count($inp_info); $i++) {
for($j=0; $j <= count($inp_info); $j++) {
```

It started working. Thanks everyone for your time and effort

Comment: It would be good if you mark this as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING - Going out on a limb here and using this as my answer without testing to confirm speed or syntax without proper data.

```
$xml_file = "C:/../data/GenericSalePrice.xml";

$header = 
<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <generic-sales-price xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
EOT;

$body = '';
for($j=0; $j<=$rows_of_data; $j++) {

    $region = $inp_info[$start_row+$j][$start_col];
    $price = $inp_info[$start_row+$j][$start_col+1];

    $temp_body = 
<<<EOT
    <sale-price>
        <region>        
            {$region}
        </region>
        <price>
            {$price}
        </price>
    </sale-price>
EOT;

    $body .= $temp_body;
}

$footer = "</generic-sales-price>";

$string = $header . $body . $footer;

file_put_contents($xml_file, $string);
```